Make that if I type something in A2 cell then in A1 cell it will show user name
Make that if I type something in A2 cell then in A1 cell it will show the user name. And I need that its work for every line. For example, If I type in A2 then JUST in A1 user name is prompting, if I type in B2 cell then JUST in B1 user name is prompting. And I need to make it for every line. Any ideas?
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B1").Value = Application.UserName
    End If
End Sub


So many examples on here of the use of index() with match() which can do this without vba.

If you want to do this in VBA then what you need is the Worksheet_Change event. You may want to see THIS. Alternatively you can use formula as shown HERE. Combine this formula with the IF Function.

If Target.Column = 2 Then Target.Offset(, -1) = Application.UserName
